# Splitting audio segment by pitch

Tags: pydub

I'm trying to use Pydub to split an audio segment by pitch. My idea is to find the timestamps when the pitch changes and split according to those timestamps.

The part I am stuck on is how to find the time when the pitch changes.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks